# PHP - use variable as operator

Tags: php, logical-operators

I am trying to get this:

```
if($a[2] > $b[2] && $c[2] < 3) echo "bingo";
```

But because the condition is retrieved from database, I need to get the whole condition into a variable and then somehow find a way to change the variable back into a condition. I thought it will be something along this line:

```
$condition = "$a[2] > $b[2] && $c[2] < 3";
$evaledCondition = eval("$condition;");
if($evaledCondition) echo "bingo";
```

Apparently it didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Becareful using `eval`...especially with user supplied data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> eval() returns NULL unless return is
>   called in the evaluated code

```
   $evaledCondition = eval("return $condition;");
```